# Visual Studio 17.9.0 Multiple startup options

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I've just upgraded to the latest Visual Studio Preview. I have a solution with 3 web projects

In a solution that I already had on my machine I see this, i.e. none of my projects are listed. Just the same it works

[image]

If I get a clean build from git, build and run it, my other web projects don't run

If I click on "create new launch profile", I can see all my projects. If I don't select anything then nothing runs (as I would expect), but if I do select some projects to run then only the non web projects run. There's nothing in the "debug target" dropdowns

Both of the web projects are .NET Framework. There is another Web.API .NET 7 project which also doesn't work

Just to add. If I right cick on one of the web projects and "set as startup project" then it works, but that's pretty useless to me as I need them all to run